# Creating zip file from folders

Tags: r

I am wondering if it is possible to create a zip file from folders. I have one folder and in this folders there are four folders and in there, there are different kind of files. Now I want to zip those four folders recursively with their files.

I tried `save()` and `gzip()` but they don't do what I want.

Has someone a hint for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Rcompression](http://www.omegahat.org/Rcompression/) package at Omegahat can do that. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(Rcompression)
d <- "C:/my_data"
files <- list.files(d, recursive=TRUE)
zip("myarchive.zip", files=paste(d, files, sep="/"), altNames=files)
```

See `?zip` for more examples.

Comment: This example helped me mostly in my case. Thank you!

Comment: Use `file.path` rather than `paste(..., sep = "/")`.

Comment: there is also a base::zip function, which is a wrapper for an external zip command

Comment: base::zip function needs R_ZIPCMD to be set in linux OS. In windows it is not needed. Something to keep in mind for cross platform development

Comment: Rcompression is no longer available

Comment: There are no binary packages, but the the [source package](http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/Rcompression_0.94-0.tar.gz) is still there..

Answer (score 22):

Scope out the tar command. While it's not zip, a compressed tar file is just as good.

```
tarfile <- 'newfile.tgz'
tar(tarfile,'/path/of/dir/to/tar/up',compression='gzip')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that tar is also cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds good but in my case I need .zip. But I keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You could look for tips in the sources of [odfWeave package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html).

If you load the library and type odfWeave, you will get the source, which is not too long and implements zipping and unzipping also with system calls.

From theese sources, you could do something like:

```
filename = '' # set archive filename
loc = ''      # set location, if not done before
setwd(loc)
zipCmd = paste("zip -r ", filename, " .", sep='')
system(zipCmd, invisible = TRUE)
```

Of course, zip must be installed.