# Create a tar from a folder in R while keeping the relative path only

Tags: r, gzip, tar

Following Jeff's reply here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627044/429846

I would like to tar a folder, but keep the path relative to the location of the folder (and not include the drive name and so on).

Sample code:

```
tarfile <- 'newfile.tgz'
tar(tarfile,file.path(getwd(), "folder_name"),compression='gzip')
```

Is it possible?  (either in "tar" or another function name)

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting? Your example code works, as does `tar(tarfile, file.path("./relative/path/", "folder_name"), compression="gzip")`... Are you wanting something else, and if so, what?

Comment: Hi Josh.  Thanks for the comment!  I see that it indeed works, but when unloaded - wouldn't it include the "./" inside the folder name?

Comment: Hi Tal. No, I don't think it will. It should (and seems to) only include the last bit (i.e. `"folder_name"`). It wouldn't otherwise be very portable... Does it do something different for you?