# Creating zip file from folders in R

Tags: r, zip

Try to create a zip file from one folder using R.

It mentioned "Rcompression" package here:
[Creating zip file from folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624360/creating-zip-file-from-folders)

But I didn't find where I can download this package for Windows system.

Any suggestions? or other functions to create a zip file?

Comment: you can call system commands from r. also `?tar` would be easier. I don't see why you need a package to do this

Comment: @rawr it is not  that easy cross platform.

Comment: oh. are you working on a non windows, unix, or mac platform?

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/omegahat/Rcompression) might help.  There are Windows-specific instructions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating zip file from folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624360/creating-zip-file-from-folders)

Answer (score 51):

You can create a zip file with the function `zip` from `utils` package quite easily. Say you have a directory `testDir` and you wish to zip a file (or multiple files) inside the directory,

```
dir('testDir')
# [1] "cats.csv" "test.csv" "txt.txt" 
zip(zipfile = 'testZip', files = 'testDir/test.csv')
# adding: testDir/test.csv (deflated 68%)
```

The zipped file is saved in the current working directory, unless a different path is specified in the `zipfile` argument.  We can see its size relative to the original unzipped file with

```
file.info(c('testZip.zip', 'testDir/test.csv'))['size']
#                  size
# testZip.zip       805
# testDir/test.csv 1493
```

You can zip the whole directory of files (if no sub-folders) with

```
files2zip <- dir('testDir', full.names = TRUE)
zip(zipfile = 'testZip', files = files2zip)
# updating: testDir/test.csv (deflated 68%)
# updating: testDir/cats.csv (deflated 27%)
# updating: testDir/txt.txt (stored 0%)
```

And `unzip` it to view the files,

```
unzip('testZip.zip', list = TRUE)
#               Name Length                Date
# 1 testDir/test.csv   1493 2014-05-14 20:54:00
# 2 testDir/cats.csv    116 2014-05-14 20:54:00
# 3  testDir/txt.txt     32 2014-05-08 09:37:00
```

**Note:** From `?zip`, regarding the `zip` argument.

> On Windows, the default relies on a zip program (for example that from Rtools) being in the path.

Comment: If I want to zip the folder "testDir", how should I do it? It may include some subfolders inside. I tyied this: zip('testZip', files = 'testDir/'), but it didn't work.

Comment: You want to zip the subfolders too?

Comment: I cannot find the zip file after running the script. Is the zip file in the same directory?

Comment: The new zip file is saved in the current working directory if you used `zip('testZip', ...)`.  You should see it with `list.files()`

Comment: If you use `utils::zip` you may need to `setwd()` to the directory in which the folder you wish to zip resides. This will enable you to have relative filenames in the zip you create.

Comment: It is strange. I searched my whole computer, but cannot find the zip file.   > getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst"
> files <- list.files("C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst/testDir")
> files
[1] "file1.pdf"  "file2.r"    "file3.docx"
> zip('newfile',files=files)
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst"
> list.files("C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst")
[1] "R.rdata" "testDir"

Comment: Try `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files()`.

Comment: Still don't work. It is weird. `files <- list.files("C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst/testDir",full.names = TRUE)`
`files`
[1] "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst/testDir/file1.pdf" 
[2] "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst/testDir/file2.r"   
[3] "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst/testDir/file3.docx"
`getwd()`
[1] "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst"
`zip(zipfile="newfile",files=files)`
`list.files("C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst",full.names = TRUE)`
[1] "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst/R.rdata" "C:/Users/zjian/Desktop/tst/testDir"'

Comment: You may need to download package `Rtools`.

Answer (score 7):

For avoiding (a) an issue with relative paths (i.e., the zip file itself containing a folder structure with the full folder path to be zipped) and (b) `for` loops (well, style), you may use

```
my_wd<-getwd() # save your current working directory path
dest_path<-"C:/.../folder_with_files_to_be_zipped" 
setwd(dest_path)
files<-list.files(dest_path)
named<-paste0(files,".zip")
mapply(zip,zipfile=named,files=files)
setwd(my_wd) # reset working directory path
```

Unlike R´s build-in `unzip` function, `zip` requires a zip-program like 7-zip (Windows) or the one being part of Rtools to be present in your system path.

Comment: The purpose of this code is to ... create one zip file per file in `folder_with_files_to_be_zipped`?

Answer (score 6):

For people still looking for this: there is now a ["zip" package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=zip) that does not depend on external executables.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that `zip()` will fail silently if it cannot find a zip program.

`zip` returns an error code (or exit code) *invisibly*. That is, it will not print, unless you explicitly ask it to.

You can run `print(zip(output, input))`, to print the exit code, which in the case of no zip program found, will print `127`

Alternatively you can do something along the lines of

```r
#exit code 0 for success, all other codes are for failure
if (exit_code <- zip(output, input) != 0) {
    stop("Zipping ", input, " failed with exit code:", exit_code)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Why is "fail silently" the default behavior for anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can install from the `omegahat` repos:

```
install.packages('Rcompression', repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source")
```

for windows you will need to jump through hoops installing zlib and bzip2 and linking appropriately.

`utils::zip` can be used in some cases. There are a number of issues with it. One case is that the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191 characters (2047 characters on some versions) for windows. If you are zipping a directory with alot of characters for the names of directories/files this will cause issues. For example if you zip your firefox profile directory. Also I found the zip command needed to be issued relative the directory I was zipping to use relative directory names. `Rcompression` has a `altNames` argument which handles this. 
That being said I have always had problems getting `Rcompression` to run on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make that

```
    #Convertir todas las carpetas en .zip
    d <- "C:/Users/Eric/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"
    array <- list.files(d)

    for (i in 1:length(array)){
      name <- paste0(array[i],".zip")

      zip(name, files = paste0(d,paste0("/",array[i])))
    }
```