# Zip files without directory name in R

Tags: r, zip

Inside working directory I have folders names ending "*_txt" containing files inside folder, want to zip all folders with original name and files inside them. Everything is working perfectly but problem in .zip contains the name of directory as well that i don't want e.g "1202_txt.zip\1202_txt\files"  needs to be "1202_txt.zip\files"

```
dir.create("1202_txt") # creating folder inside working directory

    array <- list.files( , "*_txt")

    for (i in 1:length(array)){
      name <- paste0(array[i],".zip")

      #zip(name, files = paste0(d,paste0("/",array[i])))
      zip(name, files = array[i])
    }
```

Above code is available [Creating zip file from folders in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668395/creating-zip-file-from-folders-in-r/38705870)
Note: Empty folders can be skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach I used to achieve my desired results tricky but still works

```
setwd("c:/test")
dir.create("1202_txt") # creating folder inside working directory and some CSV files in there

array <- list.files( , "*_txt")

for (i in 1:length(array)){
  name <- paste0(array[i],".zip")

  Zip_Files <- list.files(path = paste0(getwd(),"/",  array[[i]]), pattern = ".csv$")
  # Moving Working Directory
  setwd(file.path("C:\\test\\",array[[i]]))
  #zipping files inside the directory
  zip::zip(zipfile = paste0(name[[i]]), files = Zip_Files)

  # Moving zip File from Inside folder to outside
  file.rename(name[i], paste0("C:\\test\\", name[i]))
  print(name[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this? (using R 3.5.0, macOS High Sierra 10.13.6)

```
dir_array <- list.files(getwd(), "*_txt")

zip_files <- function(dir_name){
  zip_name <- paste0(dir_name, ".zip")
  zip(zipfile = zip_name, files = dir_name)
}

Map(zip_files, dir_array)
```

This should zip all the folders inside the current working directory with the specified name. The zipped folders are also housed in the current working directory.

Comment: BTW I tried your solution as far as I understand  it works as intended

Comment: Yap i know my question is complete code but i wanted output Zip must not contain the directory name inside the zip archive only the files should be shown.