# Shiny: download zip archive

Tags: r, shiny

I can't make shiny's `downloadHandler` to output the zip file:

```
# server.R
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename <- function() {
      paste("output", "zip", sep=".")
    },

    content <- function(fname) {
      fs <- c()
      tmpdir <- tempdir()
      setwd(tempdir())
      for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) {
        path <- paste0("sample_", i, ".csv")
        fs <- c(fs, path)
        write(i*2, path)
      }
      zip(zipfile=fname, files=fs)
    }
  )
})
```

And the simple `ui.R`:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("downloadData", label = "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(h6("Sample download", align = "center"))
  )
))
```

I'm having nice output, except the error:

```
> shiny::runApp('C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/test')

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7280
  adding: sample_1.csv (stored 0%)
  adding: sample_2.csv (stored 0%)
  adding: sample_3.csv (stored 0%)
  adding: sample_4.csv (stored 0%)
  adding: sample_5.csv (stored 0%)
Error opening file: 2
Error reading: 6
```

And no save dialog to save the archive. But in the `temp` folder the right archive is presented. How to properly share the archive?

Comment: Try the `library(Rcompression)` function `zip` to see whether it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624360/creating-zip-file-from-folders

Comment: Just the note, on Windows you need Rtools installed and its bin directory need to be in your PATH env, otherwise zip function will just silently do nothing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using `<-` inside the downloadHandler function and should be using `=`. Also you may need to define the `contentType`:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(
  list(server = function(input, output) {  
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("output", "zip", sep=".")
      },
      content = function(fname) {
        fs <- c()
        tmpdir <- tempdir()
        setwd(tempdir())
        for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) {
          path <- paste0("sample_", i, ".csv")
          fs <- c(fs, path)
          write(i*2, path)
        }
        zip(zipfile=fname, files=fs)
      },
      contentType = "application/zip"
    )
  }
  , ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        downloadButton("downloadData", label = "Download")
      ),
      mainPanel(h6("Sample download", align = "center"))
    )
  ))
)
```

Comment: I noticed, that the zip download does not work for me if I use the Rstudio Browser. So you might want to try it in an external browser to make sure.

Comment: I think that using `setwd` anywhere, especially in a Shiny app is quite dangerous. Use `zip(..., flags = "-j")` instead, that gets rid of the "junk path" and stores only the names of the files.

Comment: This program results in no download for me I get a download failed box at the bottom of my browser with the messafe "Failed - no file". Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Piggybacking on the comment from @jakob-r, the zip download *kind* of doesn't work in the Rstudio browser. It will default to an extension-less file, named "downloadData", which is the name of the download button, ignoring whatever name you provide. If you add the zip extension, either when saving, or by renaming the file, it works. In other browsers it works fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also compress your folder using tar:

```
output$files_tar_button <- downloadHandler(
    filename <- function() {
      paste("output", "tar", sep=".")
    },

    content <- function(file) {
      tar(file, "file/path/")
    }
  )
```