# R Shiny: Download existing file

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say I have an existing zip file (`out.zip`) in my shiny app (i.e. located on a server).  I would like to have the user be able to download this file.  This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881368/shiny-download-zip-archive).  However, that question zips files within the `downloadHandler` whereas the zip file already exists in my case.

```
library(shiny)

app <- list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        downloadButton("downloadData", label = "Download")
      ),
      mainPanel(h6("Sample download", align = "center"))
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {  
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename <- function() {
        paste("output", "zip", sep=".")
      },

      content <- function(file) {
        # not sure what to put here???
      },
      contentType = "application/zip"
    )
  }
)

shiny::runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

After poking around with different file handling functions I discovered that `file.copy` can be used to download the file.

I change `downloadHandler` to:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  filename <- function() {
    paste("output", "zip", sep=".")
  },

  content <- function(file) {
    file.copy("out.zip", file)
  },
  contentType = "application/zip"
)
```

Comment: Where does your zipped file live? Inside www folder or can it be in any folder?

Comment: @zx8754 it should be any folder you specify.  You would just need to provide the path to where you want it saved.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, "out.zip" is the file that exists in one of my app folders, right?

Comment: Does this solution works locally for instance when running Shiny through R Studio or only in a production environment? In my case the HTML of the page is downloaded instead

Answer (score 29):

A few years later, but I think there is a simpler way if you do not need dynamic file generation by placing the file in the `www/` folder of the Shiny app:

```
|
|- app.R
|- www/
       - downloadme.csv
```

Then when your Shiny app is live the file is available at `shiny-url.com/downloadme.csv` - or when testing locally `127.0.0.1:1221/downloadme.csv`

e.g. to use within your Shiny ui:

```r
# in ui somewhere
...
  a(href="downloadme.csv", "Download CSV", download=NA, target="_blank")
...
```

Comment: Thank you for including this answer. No need to over complicate things if I don't need a dynamic download.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Is there a way to have the path somewhere else not in the www/ folder by using something like "~/data/downloadme.csv"?

Comment: Not unless you copy it into the www/ folder, which is the folder that holds all the webfiles

Comment: Beautiful answer

Comment: When I open my app in the browser it shows "http://127.0.0.1:7777/" only, should something else be there as you showed in 127.0.0.1:1221/downloadme.csv?

Comment: Carlos - the Shiny port is random but you can hardcore it via options(shiny.port=1234)

Comment: For a golem Shiny app (at least), I needed to use a `www/` prefix:
`tags$a(href="www/downloadme.csv", "Download CSV", download=NA)`