# Shiny Download File based on File Path

Tags: r, shiny

I have a file which i generate in shiny
The user clicks a button and the file should download. However nothing happens

The function `export_report` generates the excel file and saves it to a location. The function then passes back the file location to the download handler so it will download the file. The problem seems to be that it isnt being returned correctly. I have tested the function (`export_report`) outside of shiny and it returns everything perfectly so I'm clearly doing something wrong from the shiny perspective.

The file itself is created where it is supposed to be on the server because i can download it within RStudio and see it in the file explorer. Can anyone help

```
# UI Section
downloadButton("downloadRpt", "Download Report")

# Server Section
output$downloadRpt <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() {
    mydf <- report()
    dateRange <- input$dates_report
    selection <- input$selection 
    myfile <- export_report (mydf, selection, dateRange)
  },
  content = function(file) {
    file.copy(myfile, file)
  }
)
```

I have seen other examples [R Shiny: Download existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416557/r-shiny-download-existing-file) which is what my code is based on

EDIT 1: Adding the export_report function with some fake data to run it

```
export_report <- function(mydf,selection,dateRange) {

  # Template for where the template excel file is stored

  myoutputTemplate <- '/home/shiny_tutorials/Save to Database/templates/output_template.xlsx' 


  start_date <- dateRange[1] 
  end_date <- dateRange[2]
  date_range <- paste(start_date ,end_date, sep = " - " )

  # Load workbook the template workbook
  wb <- loadWorkbook(myoutputTemplate)

  # write to the workbook the data frame
  writeWorksheet(wb, mydf, sheet="Details",   
             startRow=8, startCol=2,    
             header=FALSE)                

  # add the the customer the user selected
  writeWorksheet(wb, selection, sheet="Details",   
             startRow=3, startCol=3,    
             header=FALSE)   

  # date
  writeWorksheet(wb, date_range, sheet="Details",   
             startRow=5, startCol=3,    
             header=FALSE)   

  # Create The file Name
  filename <- paste(selection, Sys.Date(), sep = " - ") %>% 
    paste(.,"xlsx", sep = ".")

  # removes the % sign and extra qoutes 
  filename <- gsub (pattern = '\'|%','', x = filename)

  # output directory
  myoutput <-  paste('/home/shiny_tutorials/Save to Database/output/',
               filename, sep = '')

  # Save workbook
  saveWorkbook(wb, myoutput)

  # Return File Path
  myoutput

}
```

To call the function you can use the data below

```
dateRange <- c("2011-09-23","2016-09-23")
selection = "COMPANY_A"
mydf <- iris
myfile <- export_report(mydf,selection,dateRange)
```

**EDIT 2** I have now managed to get an error out of it. When i `cat(myfile)` in the `filename = function() {` section of the code i get the error after the correct file path has been returned

> Warning in rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
>     'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
>   Warning: Error in ifelse: replacement has length zero
>   Stack trace (innermost first):
>       1: runApp
>   Error : replacement has length zero

This error is basically because my file path does not get passed to the segment `myfile` so

**if someone can tell me how to get the filepath generated by my function to the server section of the code below, that should fix my problem**

```
content = function(file) {
    file.copy(myfile, file)
  }
```

Comment: Does your `export_report` function return a file name or a file path? inside `downloadHandler`, `filename` should be a name only (it's the name of the file user gets), and `content` contains the actual file.

Comment: Hi @warmoverflow, If that is the case, how do you specify where the actual file is to download? For example my file is contained in a folder called root\output\output_company - 29-05-82

Comment: The actual file path is to be used in the `file.copy` command (first argument), while the file name is to be used as the `filename` variable in `downloadHandler`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who commented and clarified my thinking a bit on how the download handler works.
In the end, i created a new function which split up the export function above
The new function i used is called `generate_file()` which simply returns the file name

```
generate_file_name <- function(selection) {

  # Create The file Name
  filename <- paste(selection, Sys.Date(), sep = " - ") %>% 
    paste(.,"xlsx", sep = ".")

  # removes the % sign and extra qoutes 
  filename <- gsub (pattern = '\'|%','', x = filename)

  # output directory
  myoutput <-  paste('/home/shiny_tutorials/Save to Database/output/',
                 filename, sep = '')

  # Return File Path
  myoutput
```

}

Then in the server side

```
output$downloadRpt <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    selection <- input$company
    generate_file_name(selection)
  },

  content = function(file) {

    mydf <- report()
    dateRange <- input$dates_report
    selection <- input$company
    export_report(mydf,selection,dateRange)
    myfile <- generate_file_name(selection)
    file.copy(myfile, file)

  }
)
```

This then finds the newly created file and exports it for the user

Answer (score 3):

I just checked your problem with this example code and it worked:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
        data <- mtcars
        myfile <- "data.csv"
        write.csv(data, myfile)
        myfile
    },
    content = function(file) {
        print(file) //prints: [...]\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpEBYDXT\\fileab8c003878.csv
        file.copy(file, file)
    }
)
```

*myfile* is the filename of the downloaded file. You cannot use it in *file.copy* as input, this variable is out of scope. It seems that R creates a temp file name (see the print()).

Comment: Hi @Lars K. Thank you for helping me with this. Can you tell me what exactly the `filename` portion of the `downloadhandler` is for? It doesn't seem to be getting used anywhere how is the path getting passed to the file.copy. My question is because what if two people are running the web page at the same time, how does it know which one to download. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Hi John, I am not that much into Shiny. filename = *myfile* is the output file name, proposed to the user for downloading. But you use it for storing your xlsx file, too. In my tiny example, Shiny keeps data.csv in a common directory for every session. In your case, maybe you store your xlsx to tempfile = "Table(SessionId).xlsx" and return myfile = "Table.xslx". Of course, tempfile should be determined outside downloadHandler in order to be found in content = function(file){file.copy(tempfile, file)}. Hope, I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `filename` function to define your path or a custom file name, and the `write.csv` in the content part. Example code:

```
 output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
        paste(<user_name or date for eg>, ".csv", sep="")
        },
    content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data, file)
    }    
 )
```

I noticed in your comment above, you have asked how the application would generate the correct file when used by multiple users. For this part, you need to use the `session`.

So if your business logic functions were to come from an R file called foo.R, the server code should look something like:

```
shinyServer(func = function(input, output, session) {
     source("./foo.R", local=TRUE)
     ......
```

And this would separate out the session for each user, thereby generating files specific to each, when downloading. Hope this gives you some pointers.