# Download excel file already existing in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to donwload an excel file already existing in my shiny app.

I've tried following code in `server.R`

```
   output$downloadbutton <- downloadHandler(

     filename <- function() {
       paste("result_balance", "xlsx", sep=".")
     },
     content <- function(file) {
       #temp <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
       file.copy(file.path(getwd(),'www','result.xlsx'), file,overwrite = TRUE)
     },
     contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
   )
```

but when user click on Download button it appears a download pop up like this:

[image]

and it will download a folder with xml/html files in it.
Weird is that the proposed name is downloadbutton like my id shiny element.

I'm already aware of this [R Shiny: Download existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416557/r-shiny-download-existing-file).

R version 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

`filename` and `content` are arguments of the function `downloadHandler`, thus you have to use `=` and not `<-`:

```
 output$downloadbutton <- downloadHandler(

     filename = function() {
       paste("result_balance", "xlsx", sep=".")
     },
     content = function(file) {
       #temp <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
       file.copy(file.path(getwd(),'www','result.xlsx'), file,overwrite = TRUE)
     },
     contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
   )
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice. But the weird things is that in windows download is ok with the code I posted, in Linux I got the problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on windows and linux ( Ubuntu) this function works:

```
 output$downloadbutton <- downloadHandler(

     filename = function() {
       paste("result_balance", "xlsx", sep=".")
     },
     content = function(file) {

       file.copy(file.path(getwd(),'www','result.xlsx'), file,overwrite = TRUE)
     },
     contentType = "text/xlsx"
   )
```