# Download A File Generated Within An R Shiny App

Tags: r, csv, shiny, download, shinydashboard

I am currently trying to generate a Shiny App that at the press of a button generates and downloads data for a user. I have a user defined function that pulls data from some places, analyzes, and creates a .csv comprised of numerous tables.

The bottleneck I'm running into is successfully taking this .csv file comprised of multiple tables  and allowing it to be easily downloaded. I have tried applying the [solution presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416557/r-shiny-download-existing-file), but when I run the application script, all of the data is generated from the button but it doesn't bring up the download window as I'd hoped. Is there a way of using `downloadHandler` and link it to something other than a `downloadButton` or `downloadLink` function?

Current UI Function:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Download Center"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="mytabs",
                sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    
  tabItem(tabName = "DataHarah", h2("Download Your Data Here"),
                  textInput(inputId='startyear', label='What is the first year?'
                            ,value=2021, width = NULL, placeholder = "Inputs should be
                            a four digit year (e.g. 2022)."),
          textInput(inputId='endyear', label='What is the last year?'
                    ,value=2022, width = NULL, placeholder = "Inputs should be
                            a four digit year (e.g. 2022)."),
          actionButton("do", "Generate & Download Your Data!")      
                 ))
  ))
```

Current Server Function & Initialization:

```
observeEvent(input$do,
               {DataTalk(input$startyear,input$endyear) # function that generates a csv file
                                                        # containing multiple tables.
                 
                 output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(  #download handler that may not be connected properly.
                   filename = c('mycsv.csv'),
                   content = function(file){
                     file.copy('mycsv.csv',file)})})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It sounds like the data you want users to be able to download is in-memory. The [server code in the example here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html) takes in-memory data created as a `reactive()` value, and writes it to csv within a `downloadHandler()`. This may be a strategy you explore.