# Save/download multiple objects from the app with one save button

Tags: r, shiny

**Context:** I have an app transforming data according to user's choices. It creates a few tables and plots in the process.

**Objective:** to save some objects created in the process into one new folder with one click on a button.

**Previous researches:** the code below saves objects using `downloadHandler()` and some functions as presented [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html). It does not seems to allow multiple objects to be passed into `downloadHandler()`. I am aware it is possible to stack these objects in a list and then save it but if possible I would like to avoid doing it and instead get multiple files (like .txt or .png, ...)

Here is a reproductible example with very little data using datasets included in R (`mtcars` and `iris`).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    downloadButton("save", "Save") # one click on this button to save df1 AND df2 tables in a new folder
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    # my real app does multiple changes on datasets based on user choices
    df1 = mtcars[1:10,]
    df2 = iris[1:10,]

    # Now I want to save df1 and df2 objects with 1 click on the "Save" button

    output$save = downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){ paste("example", ".txt", sep = " ") },
        content = function(file) { write.table(df1, file) }
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Many thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: I think you need to zip the files and then pass the zip to downloadHandler

Comment: Based on you suggestion I'll try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881368/shiny-download-zip-archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments of the linked post, it's not typically a good idea to change the working directory (and unnecessary in this case). While inconsequential with a small number of files, the `paste0` call to create the path doesn't need to be in the `for` loop as it is vectorized. This also eliminates the need to dynamically grow the `fs` vector (also generally a bad practice). Lastly, my `zip` utility wasn't on my path which caused the `utils::zip` to fail (you can specify the path in the function call, otherwise it checks for the environment variable `R_ZIPCMD` and defaults to 'zip' assuming it to be on the path).

I generally agree with the accepted answer, but here's an alternative solution using the `zip::zipr` function instead (also `walk` instead of the `for` loop)

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(zip)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("save", "Save") # one click on this button to save df1 AND df2 tables in a new folder
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # my real app does multiple changes on datasets based on user choices
  df1 <- mtcars[1:10,]
  df2 <- iris[1:10,]

  # need to names these as user won't be able to specify
  fileNames <- paste0("sample_", 1:2, ".txt")

  output$save = downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){ paste0("example", ".zip") },
    content = function(file) { 

      newTmpDir <- tempfile()
      if(dir.create(newTmpDir)){

        # write data files
        walk2(list(df1, df2), fileNames, 
                        ~write.table(.x, file.path(newTmpDir, .y))
        )

        # create archive file
        zipr(file, files = list.files(newTmpDir, full.names = TRUE))

      }
    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your clear answer. I have tried not to use the `zip` package unsuccessfully. I trust your experience and implement it as you propose.