# zip files with R

Tags: r, zip

I am combining Tableau Software and Rstudio Tools.
I have a Template(Dashboard) where I inject different value of DATA after Rcode processing.

I want to reproduce a workbook (.twbx)
to do that manually I compress (Data + Dashboard.twb) with 7-zip with .twbx extension

But when I try to do the same thing with R, `zip`  function point out an Error

```
d<- "~/Myriam/Projets/Data/Dashboard_Template"
files <- list.files(d, recursive=TRUE)
zip("myarchive.zip", files=paste(d, files, sep="/"))
```

> **Warning message:**
>   running command '"zip" -r9X "myarchive.zip" "~/Myriam/Projets/Data/Dashboard_Template/Dashboard_Template.twb" "~/Myriam/Projets/Data/Dashboard_Template/Data/Data/Categorie.txt" "~/Myriam/Projets/Data/Dashboard_Template/Data/Data/db_histo_fake_table_subset.txt" ' **had status 127**

```
Sys.getenv('R_ZIPCMD')
# [1] ""
```

The Code that I used

`d<- "~/Myriam/Projets/Data/Dashboard_Template" 
files <- list.files(d, recursive=TRUE) 
zip("myarchive.zip", files=paste(d, files, sep="/"))`

Sys.getenv('R_ZIPCMD') returns ""

```
   Sys.getenv('R_ZIPCMD') 
   [1] ""
```

I dont have this problem with `tar()` function even if it is in the same Library utils and `Sys.getenv('tar')` returns ""

Thank you

Comment: please edit your question with this info and not use comments

Comment: looks like you either do not have a zip utility installed or it is just not in your path. can you try the suggestions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624360/creating-zip-file-from-folders)?

Comment: It is a environnement path problem, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with variable environment PATH,
I appended the following directories to PATH:

```
path: ..........;C:\Program Files\Rtools\bin
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: How did you append directories to PATH?

Comment: see `?zip`: On Windows, the default relies on a zip program (for example that from Rtools - Rtools\bin\zip.exe) being in the path.